# listener for Plotter library doesn't work

Tags: serial, library

I try to use [Plotter](https://github.com/devinaconley/arduino-plotter) to plot some data from my Adafruit Circuitplayground board, but the listener is kept showing "Scanning serial ports..." and not displaying any plot (as shown below in the picture).
[image]

I have java 1.8.0_271 installed (in order to run listener) and I put the listener folder under the same directory as the Arduino code file (though I'm not sure if there's a requirement of where to put the listener folder). Arduino is the latest version. Code is copied from the sample code of the Plotter library

Comment: close the console window

Comment: @jsotola if I close the Serial monitor Listener will be turned off automatically